# Defining several steps for the same function in Cucumber JVM

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there any way to have more than one step definition (of the same type) for the same function? Something like:

```
@Then("^it's do something$")
@Then("^it's do another thing$")
public void this_is_my_function() throws Throwable {
   // Do something
}
```

I now that in Behat (PHP) and Specflow (C#) it is possible.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(86, 5) java: cucumber.api.java.en.Then is not a repeatable annotation type
```

I found a [post](http://softwarecave.org/2014/05/20/repeating-annotations-in-java-8/) talking about the repeatable problem but the following solution didn't work.

```
@Thens({
    @Then("^it's do something$")
    @Then("^it's do another thing$")
})
```

I guess I should define @Thens as a new annotation type, but I would like to depen only in what the library has. Is not any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it into one @Then:

```
@Then("^(?:it's do something|it's do another thing)$")
public void this_is_my_function() throws Throwable {
   // Do something
}
```